# Duplicate button error on Admin->Create Order Page using existing customer

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.9

[image]I am using Magento Enterprise 2.1.9 version. On Create Order Page (admin) if I change customer group, buttons "Add Products By SKU" and "Add Products" are getting duplicate. This is a existing bug in Magento. Can anyone please help me how to rectify this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug, there is an error in magento2.1.9 js file. they are using label property instead of _label .

File path

vendor\module-sales\web\order\create\scripts.js

Replace this code

```
        this.summarizePrice = true;
        jQuery.async('#order-items', (function(){
            this.dataArea = new OrderFormArea('data', $(this.getAreaId('data')), this);
            this.itemsArea = Object.extend(new OrderFormArea('items', $(this.getAreaId('items')), this), {
                addControlButton: function(button){
                    var controlButtonArea = $(this.node).select('.actions')[0];
                    if (typeof controlButtonArea != 'undefined') {
                        var buttons = controlButtonArea.childElements();         
                        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {  
                            if (buttons[i].innerHTML.include(button.label)) {
                                return ;
                            }
                        }
                        button.insertIn(controlButtonArea, 'top');
                    }
                }
            });
```

---

By this code:

```
        this.summarizePrice = true;
        jQuery.async('#order-items', (function(){
            this.dataArea = new OrderFormArea('data', $(this.getAreaId('data')), this);
            this.itemsArea = Object.extend(new OrderFormArea('items', $(this.getAreaId('items')), this), {
                addControlButton: function(button){
                    var controlButtonArea = $(this.node).select('.actions')[0];
                    if (typeof controlButtonArea != 'undefined') {
                        var buttons = controlButtonArea.childElements();         
                        for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {  
                            if (buttons[i].innerHTML.include(button._label)) {
                                return ;
                            }
                        }
                        button.insertIn(controlButtonArea, 'top');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: I want to rename the existing Add Product button. any idea ???